# handling large bitmaps in OpenGL ES and Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, culling

I created a map app that uses a very large image as my map. It shows high resolution tiles when the user zooms in to a certain degree and a lower-res bitmap of the whole image when zoomed out past 50%. It works OK, on my origional droid sometimes I can see a very slight lag due to the new tiles being drawn into and from the garbage collector.

Im now thinking about how OpenGL ES would be a better way to render. Ive never touched it before, but from what ive been reading in different turoials, it seems i could create a quad that has 8 faces or so, and enable culling so it only draws the images that are currently visible on the screen.

Would this eliminate the lag completely? In my test app now I have tiles being loaded on app startup but i can tell the lag is due to those tiles being drawn for the first time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written an OpenGL-based map view and it's bloody awesome if I say so myself. Sadly it's for a commercial project so I can't offer code. I can however tell you that it has 1 rendering thread, a pool of 8 tile downloading threads, and (most pertinent to your question) 1 storage thread that loads and saves tiles to the NAND flash or the SD card. Rendering is done one tile at a time, each tile being 2 triangles (there are no quads in ES). It's still blisteringly quick.

Comment: awesome. How big was the resolution of your map? Mine is pretty large ,6656 by 4880 i believe.

Comment: How do you mean? It's world-sized, at 18 zoom levels... prob around the order of 1TB of data.

Comment: Each tile was 256x256 pixels on HDPI screens, for MDPI it was 128x128. The server allowed both.

Comment: I should add that you might not need to go the route of opengl... just take your I/O off your UI thread and any lag should disappear.

Comment: @ReubenScratton how do you handle the touch event?